# License file not present in my final APK if i am using Dexguard

Tags: android, dexguard

I added my license file into src folder. If I generate the APK without using dexguard my license file is present in META-INF folde but if I am using dexguard the license file is not present in META-INF folder.

In build.gradle file I added the below line:-

proguardFile getDefaultDexGuardFile('dexguard-release-aggressive.pro')

If I remove this line ,I will get license file in META-INF folder if I added this line the license file is not present in META-INF folder.

I need my license file to be part of my final APK MEAT-INF folder.

How can I achieve this?

Please help me!